# Can storing large images in drawable-nodpi folder cause OutOfMemory exceptions

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

I'm thinking whether it is a good practice to store all images in drawable-nodpi folder instead of storing different size images in drawable-ldpi, mdpi, etc.

Let's say I keep all my images in drawavle-nodpi. Images are at least 720x1280 size. I run my app on device having screen resolutions of 240x320. How will it handle images from drawable-nodpi. Will those images be scaled down during runtime or will it be shown as they are. Can it cause OOM exceptions? I think that if those large images are loaded into memory they may cause OOM because devices with small screens usually have less RAM and heap size but I am not sure. It looks like storing all images in drawavle-nodpi would make developer's life much easier.

Comment: it will use it as it is..  and yeah it bring about alota exceptions.. locating or specifying drawable helps android to know which image to use for a particular screen.. but if you dont. **Bomboclat** ..lol

Comment: What are the use cases for these images? Also, are you aware of android asset studio. http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ This site makes dealing with the various resource sizes much easier.

Answer (score 1):

> Will those images be scaled down during the runtime or will it be
>   shown as they are.

No they are not. They will be loaded in an independent density way. They will be shown as they are

```
 Can it cause OOM exceptions?
```

of course, that depends mainly on two factors. The former is the device's (application) heap and the latter is how big are those images and how many you keep in ram

Answer (score 0):

It will be pixel per pixel in every device, so it will not be scaled down or up, so in a small device the images will be huge, and in a tablet, it will be tiny.

The purpose of using ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and so on, is that images have a reasonable similar size in different screens.

About memory, it will probably cause memory problems in small devices, and none in big devices, since the memory allocated is for the scaled version of the file, and not the file itself, putting in nodpi would make it allocate the file itself, since it will be 1 per 1 ratio.

Comment: PS: If you want to have more memory for your app, you should use the flag android:largeHeap="true" on your application inside AndroidManifest.xml ;)

Comment: according to android docs its not a good solution to use android:largeHeap="true" just to cover up  out of memory exception

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem will be the total memory of the resources (images) and the performance when (lets say) an image view trying to display that **huge** image . From my experience, creating a -smaller size image to multiple screen is more memory and performance wise. Just for tips, you can use the automatic resizer : https://code.google.com/p/9patch-resizer/

For the exception, i never got that exception but i think it is very possible to get OOM if the image is very huge.